# TYPO3 Every internal link (Navigation too) has a target=_blank

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x, fluid-styled-content

after an upgrade from v7.6 to v8.7 and executing the upgrade wizard every link in content and navigation has a target="_blank".

Can anybody help me?

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the value of PAGE_TARGET to a empty value in TypoScript constants:

```
[PAGE_TARGET] =
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Typoscript:

- To open internal links in the same window:

  - either set `config.intTarget = _self` ([TYPO3 11 documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/Setup/Config/Index.html#inttarget))
  - or completely remove `config.intTarget`, as [`_self` is the default `<a>` `target` attribute value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a#attr-target)
- To open external links in a new tab/window:

  - set `config.extTarget = _blank` ([TYPO3 11 documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/11.5/en-us/Setup/Config/Index.html#exttarget))